# net.Conn never receiving EOF

Tags: http, go, tcp

I'm trying to send an HTTP request over a `net.Conn` TCP connection and read the subsequent response, but I never seem to receive an `EOF` from the connection when reading. This makes functions like `io.Copy` or `ioutil.ReadAll` useless, as they block forever.

#### Code:

`client.go`

```golang
const requestString = "GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: 127.0.0.1:8080\r\n\r\n"

func main() {
    dialer := net.Dialer{}
    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(requestString))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    data := make([]byte, 0)
    length := 0

    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Printf("Read error: %v\n", err)
            }
            break
        }

        data = append(data, buf[:n]...)
        length += n
        fmt.Printf("Partial read:\n%s\n", string(buf[:n]))
    }

    fmt.Println("Response:")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

`server.go`

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s", r.URL.Path[1:])
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Output of running `client.go` with `server.go` already running:

```
Partial read:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2020 04:09:32 GMT
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Hello, test
```

The first call to `Read()` returns the expected response, but lacks an `EOF`. The subsequent call to `Read()` hangs forever, and I'm not sure how to determine when the connection has finished. If I interrupt the server process, the client connection closes properly and the response is complete.

How can I either a) receive an `EOF` or b) determine when the response is complete? All examples I've seen online have something close to my code working, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The client is waiting for the server to close the connection.  There are two possible fixes 1) Add request header `Connection: close` to force server to close the connection after the response is written 2) exit after reading number of bytes specified in the response content length header or the reading the final chunk in a chunked encoding.  Unrelated: The application code that reads the response body can be replaced with `data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(conn)`.

Comment: `Connection: close` solved the issue. Thanks for noticing my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Connection: close` to the request headers makes sure that the connection... well, closes.